# why subtracting these simultaneous equations does not produce a correct answer?

Tags: linear-algebra

consider the below simultaneous equations:

x + 1.00001y = 2.99999

0.99999x + y = 2.99998

When you subtract the two equations you get

0.00001x + 0.00001y = 0.00001

which is equivalent to

x+y=1

one of the solutions to x+y=1 is x=y=0.5 but if you substitute these into the original simultaneous equations it does not work

does this mean subtracting simultaneous equations does not conserve their solutions?

Comment: $1-0.99999\ne 0.11111$.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: i got this here $\left\{ x=- 199998.0,y= 199999.0 \right\} $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When subtracting you correctly got to $x+y=1$.

One of the solutions to that *is* $x=y=0.5$ however notice that $x+y=1$ is a line and has infinitely many pairs $(x,y)$ that satisfy it.

What you can say for certain however is that if you graph your original two lines and your newly made line, they will all intersect at the same exact place since the newly made line is a "linear combination" of the first two.

What you should do is from $x+y=1$ note that it implies that $x=1-y$.  Using that go into one of the original equations and replace $x$ with $1-y$ wherever you saw an $x$.  Then you will have $x + 1.00001y = (1-y) + 1.00001y = 2.99999$ which is an equation in a single variable.  This can be solved using elementary methods to find out the exact value of $y$ for the $(x,y)$ pair that simultaneously satisfies both of the first two (and subsequently the third) equations.

Now that you have what $y$ has to be, you can plug it into any of the three equations (the third looks easiest to use so I'd use that) in order to find the $x$.

---

tldr: the newly formed line intersects the first two at the same point, but must still be used in conjunction with one or both of the original two equations to finish.

Answer (score 0):

This is even more basic that the problem (rightfully) mentioned by @Sami in a comment: your aim is to solve a system of two equations, say (1) and (2). You (rightfully) noted that (1) and (2) imply a third equation, say (3), and you (rightfully) noted that x=y=0.5 solves (3). And so what? There is no reason to expect that x=y=0.5 should solve (1) or (2), is there? To summarize:

- (1) & (2) $\implies$ (3)
- x=y=0.5 $\implies$ (3)

But from these there is no reason to expect that:

- x=y=0.5 $\implies$ (1) & (2)

And (incidentally) no reason either to expect that:

- (1) & (2) $\implies$ x=y=0.5

Comment: what about the equations x-2y = 16 and x+3y=10 when you subtract them you get a solution to the equations

Comment: Please explain in detail what you have in mind, at present it is impossible to say.